# What are some good resources for learning about photonic qubits?

Tags: resource-request, experimental-realization, photonics, optical-quantum-computing

I am interested in resources that would allow me to learn about the physics behind optical quantum computation, and specifically, the physical properties of photonic qubits. I have some good resources on quantum optics, but is there anything more specific (for instance, any good review papers) I should be reading alongside this material?

Comment: Have you already read section 7.4 of Nielsen and Chuang?

Comment: this review should contain more than enough references to get you started: [Flamini et al. 2018](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1361-6633/aad5b2)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a handful of Linear Optical Quantum Computation (LOQC) resources I have found useful in the past:

- **["Linear Optical Quantum Computing"](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0512071) (2005) by Kok et. al.**: this is probably the best review paper that came out after Knill, Laflamme, and Milburn's 2001 discovery that theoretically-efficient LOQC was possible. It's a pretty thorough but very accessible introduction to the field of LOQC circa 2005. Note that this specifically focusses on "linear" photonic quantum computing.
- **"Introduction to optical quantum information processing" (2010) by Kok and Lovett**:  This book (published by Cambridge university press) covers optical information processing more generally, so it also includes content on the non-linear "continuous variable" photonic encodings.
- **["Towards practical linear optical quantum computing"](https://ethos.bl.uk/OrderDetails.do?uin=uk.bl.ethos.702792) (2015) by Gimeno-Segovia**: Chapter 2 of Gimeno-Segovia's thesis does an excellent job of reviewing the literature and progress in LOQC of the previous decade in an accessible way for new readers. The subsequent Chapters 4 to 6 then present the groundbreaking work her and her collaborators did to present a far more efficient scheme for LOQC.
- **["Why I am optimistic about the silicon-photonic route to quantum computing"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1607.08535)
   (2016) by Rudolph**: This takes the work of Gimeno-Segovia, et. al. and presents the key sets of open problems for the field of LOQC, and argues why (and suggestions for how) these can be addressed.
- **["Towards realistic architectures for linear optical quantum computing"](https://ethos.bl.uk/OrderDetails.do?uin=uk.bl.ethos.774447)
   (2019) by Morley-Short**: Chapter 2 of Morley-Short's thesis provides a top-to-bottom overview of the entire LOQC architecture (which include the discoveries of Gimeno-Segovia, et. al.) circa 2019, going all the way from single photons to algorithms on quantum error-corrected logical qubits.

Note that this does not include much content on the advances of non-linear optical quantum computing since 2010, which may also be of interest.

Comment: Also, I hadn't read gIS's suggestion, so didn't list it, but skimming over it, it looks like a good one too.

Answer (score 2):

a good stater i would say is the paper of Knill and Laflamme about LOQC (Linear Optical Quantum computing) from 2001, that says that quantum computing can be achieved with linear optic.

Photons are really good as they can be used in many way to create qubits (polarisation of course, but also time, frequency, OAM).

A Ph.D Thesis of Laurent Olislager is available online on the subject of time-frequency photon qubits, that is very interesting !